# R: Problem with specifying column using data.table v1.14.8

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table

I have a problem with specifying column using data.table v1.14.8. Below are the examples of what doesn't work and what works. Using the original dataset, which I want to make work, doesn't work.

## What doesn't work (original dataset)

```
  vars.row <- c("category", "subcategory", "variable")
  
  nrows <- length(vars.row)
  
  
  d <-
    structure(list(category = c("", "\\\\[-6pt]Scheduling", "\\\\[-6pt]Scheduling", 
                              "\\\\[-6pt]Scheduling", "\\\\[-6pt]Scheduling", "\\\\[-6pt]Statistics", 
                              "\\\\[-6pt]Statistics", "\\\\[-6pt]Statistics", "\\\\[-6pt]Statistics", 
                              "\\\\[-6pt]Statistics", "\\\\[-6pt]Statistics"), 
                   subcategory = c("", 
                               "New Procedures", "New Procedures", "New Partners", "New Partners", 
                               "", "", "", "", "", ""), 
                   variable = c("(Intercept)", "New procedures", 
                                 "(New procedures)$^2$", "New partners", "(New partners)$^2$", 
                                 "Adj. R$^2$", "AIC", "AICc", "BIC", "Deviance", "N")
                                 ), 
              row.names = c(NA, -11L), 
              class = c("data.table", "data.frame")
              )   # .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x1410254e0>

  for(i in 1:nrows){
    var <- vars.row[i]
    for(j in nrow(d):2){
      if(d[j, ..var] == d[j-1, ..var]) d[j, ..var] <- ''
    }
  }
```

## What works (fake dataset)

```
vars.row <- c("category", "subcategory")
  
  nrows <- length(vars.row)
  
  d <-
    data.frame(
      category = c(rep('A', 5), rep('B', 5)),
      subcategory = c(rep('a', 3), rep('b', 3), rep('c', 4))
    )
  
  for(i in 1:nrows){
    var <- vars.row[i]
    for(j in nrow(d):2){
      if(d[j, ..var] == d[j-1, ..var]) d[j, ..var] <- ''
    }
  }
```

Comment: Update: I used @r2evans's solution below, and please let me know if anyone has a idea why the original code wouldn't work for the original dataset. Thank you!

Comment: Does it work pre 1.14.8?

Comment: @janorecki It has worked with `d[j, var]` before the version update!

Comment: If it is a regression then should be reported to GitHub issue tracker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the bug, but we can do what I think you're trying to do with:

```r
for (var in vars.row) d[get(var) == shift(get(var)), c(var) := ""]
d
#                 category    subcategory             variable
#                   <char>         <char>               <char>
#  1:                                              (Intercept)
#  2: \\\\[-6pt]Scheduling New Procedures       New procedures
#  3:                                     (New procedures)$^2$
#  4:                        New Partners         New partners
#  5:                                       (New partners)$^2$
#  6: \\\\[-6pt]Statistics                          Adj. R$^2$
#  7:                                                      AIC
#  8:                                                     AICc
#  9:                                                      BIC
# 10:                                                 Deviance
# 11:                                                        N
```

or without the `for` loop:

```r
d[, c(vars.row) := lapply(.SD, function(z) { z[z == shift(z)] <- ""; z; }), 
  .SDcols = vars.row]
```

Comment: A suggestion was made that this question should be closed as a dupe, and that I should not have provided an answer. If the commenter that made this suggestion knows of a dupe, that's fine, then by the standards of StackOverflow this question should be closed as a duplicate, with or without my answer. The commenter tends to delete their own comments and flag others' comments as inappropriate (since deleted, including the OP's comment!), so the conversation leading to the result is masked or confusing; let's keep this conversation "open": if you think this is a dupe, please help me find it.